# How use API Google map SDK Nativeproject

Tags: android, api, vue.js, nativescript

I follow this tutorial to use gmap on my web application:
https://blog.angelengineering.com/nativescript-maps/

But I don't understand how use API and specialy the main problem it's to use keystore for use my API key.

If you can help me how use this API and what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the plugin docs [here](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk#configure-api-key-for-android)

Which, in summary amount to:

1. in `app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values` create a file named `nativescript-google-maps-sdk.xml` and put the following text in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="nativescript_google_maps_api_key">YOUR_API_KEY_HERE</string>
</resources>
```

obviously, replace YOUR_API_KEY_HERE with the actual API key you've received from Google.

2. Edit the AndroidManifest.xml file at `app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following lines just under the closing tag for the  block:

```
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/nativescript_google_maps_api_key" />
```

3. for iOS there is another method that consists of adding code into the app.js startup file. see the docs for details on that.

That should do it for you.